# Regex MatchEvaluator doesn't work with words contains "_" underscore

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to match and format output regex result. I have a words array e.g:

```
var resultArray = new List {"new", "new_"}; // notice the word with underscore
```

But when i try to search a sentence like this: 
**New Law_Book_with_New_Cover**
it does match the with the first word "New" but not the middle one with **"New_"**. here is my code

```
 if (resultArray.Count > 0)
 {
            string regex = "\\b(?:" + String.Join("|", resultArray.ToArray()) + ")\\b";
            MatchEvaluator myEvaluator = new MatchEvaluator(GetHighlightMarkup);
            return Regex.Replace(result, regex, myEvaluator, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 }

    private static string GetHighlightMarkup(Match m)
    {
        return string.Format("<span class=\"focus\">{0}</span>", m.Value);
    }
```

And yes i did tried escaping the word **"\New_"** but no luck still. 
What am i missing ?

Comment: `_` is part of the word character class, thus `\b` will not match between underscore and letters

Comment: @SebastianProske what is the work around ?

Comment: You could use lookarounds, e.g. `(?<![a-zA-Z])New(?![a-zA-Z])`

Comment: @SebastianProske and the Olympics medal goes to you! post it as an aswer

Comment: In addition to @WiktorStribiżew's answer: sorting the `resultArray` in item length descending order should help avoiding the [`New|New_`](https://regex101.com/r/mT7jU5/1) vs [`New_|New`](https://regex101.com/r/sM8iJ1/1) issue, so do `resultArray.Sort((s1, s2) => s2.Length - s1.Length);` before `string regex = ...`

Comment: Yeah, and to add to Sebastian's comment: I guess OP needs to check for alphanumerics on both sides, not just letters. DotNetDreamer, you have not specified what the result should be: `<span class="focus">New</span> Law_Book_with_<span class="focus">New</span>_Cover` or `<span class="focus">New</span> Law_Book_with_<span class="focus">New_</span>Cover`?

Comment: So will you let us answer the question? Why did Sebastian's solution work? It does not find `New_`, it finds `New`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it does. The results for me worked

Comment: Why? If you explain, that will make it possible to provide a valid answer that will be helpful to *all readers*, not just for you. "It does not work" or "it works" are not helpful to anyone. At least provide the expected result in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to match your items only if they are not enclosed with letters.

You may replace the word boundaries in your regex with lookarounds:

```
string regex = @"(?<!\p{L})(?:" + String.Join("|", resultArray.ToArray()) + @")(?!\p{L})";
```

where `\p{L}` matches any letter, `(?<!\p{L})` requires the absence of a letter before the match, and `(?!\p{L})` disallows a letter after the match.